# Using ajax for using a javascript variable to set a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am fairly new to web development and java script. I have a script that 
calls a URL to get an object. In that object there is a flag based on which I invoke a script to show me a banner. If that flag is not set then I use the rest of PHP script is used to show me some other html banner.

I am trying to do something like below.

All this in a single PHP file say myPHP.php

```
<code>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var url = 'some-URL-here';
isInterested = SomeVar.isInterested("some-argument");
if(isInterested['interest-flag'])
{
    document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+url);
    document.write ("&amp;impid="+isInterested['impression']);
    document.write ("&amp;force_adv_id="+isInterested['ad']); 
    document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
    set a php-myFlag = isInterested['interest-flag'];
}
</script>
</code>

if(php-myflag == false)
{
//Execute the usual PHP code for the banner.
}
```

So basically I want to set the PHP flag in my script code and then check it to call another PHP code to execute.

I understand that there are numerous threads in stackoverflow for java script and PHP communication. I understand that I can perhaps use  ajax to do something like this. I don't know how to use ajax in this case. Is there a way to do it without ajax as well.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is run server-side and JavaScript client-side. You can transfer data that the user entered to ANOTHER PHP script. But you cannot use PHP "after" JavaScript on the same page.

JavaScript is executed AFTER PHP is executed, so there is a possibility to pass PHP variables to JavaScript but this is not possible backwards.